# Facebook Messanger App Webhooks only HTTPS?

Tags: facebook, http, https, webhooks

I am trying to configure my bot with facebook messanger through webhooks. But when I put my url into the webhook url field I get a message that it is not an HTTPS url. Did they force it to be only HTTPS? Does that mean that everyone who wants to set up his custom webhooks needs to set up SSL certs too?

Comment: it was always https only afaik. not sure what answer you expect, to be honest. isn´t it clear that you need https if it says so?

Comment: @luschn my problem is that i am using a complex demo virtualized environment with virtual box. And to do all that is a bit of a hustle because the product is modular and served upon different docker images. (complex infrastructure)

Comment: @luschn I think ngrok might be the only possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, from facebook's  [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference/webhooks)

**Webhook Security**

All webhook calls to developer-defined callback URLs are made via HTTPS, ensuring transport-level security for webhook payloads.

To provide additional security a HTTP header X-Hub-Signature is included in each POST payload, which you should use to verify that the payload came from a Facebook server.